# Howto debug a Windows (RDP) login process?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows

I am having an issue here, where users are no more able to logon to a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine running RD services. After successfull logon, they just get a black screen presented. This does also apply to temporarily created local users trying to log on at the console (non AD users), so the RD Services and profiles can be ruled out.

When booting in Safe mode users can login and see the desktop. Also group policies can be ruled out as a culprit, as it works when booting in 'safe mode with networking' (i see the gpo are getting applied).

We also removed sophos antivirus for testing purpose... I am kind of stuck here, the event log doesnt reveal anything useful.

I would like to know at which point of the login process stucks. So how can I debug the logon process or further diagnose this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Did you recently patch the server? From my inbox this week: KB3003743 breaks RDP patch... again - HPS Help:
http://help.howproblemsolution.com/463463/kb3003743-breaks-rdp-patch-again

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/57920-KB3003743-breaks-RDP-patch-again?p=968794#post968794

https://twitter.com/jasondhart/status/532539634987712512

Comment: thx for replying, "unfortunately" this patch is not installed. also rds can be ruled out as the culprit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to "solve" it by pulling out yesterdays backup tape... however while researching I found the following links helpfully when it came to debugging. Especially the first one, as I am not sure if the second one is still applicable to Windows Server 2012 R2:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx
http://kb.ncomputing.com/kb/Debug-logon-issues-with-Userenv-logging_244.pdf